# Not able to launch apache hive through cli

Tags: hive, hortonworks-data-platform

I have kerberized Hadoop Hortonworks cluster running. Beeline works fine.
But When I am launching hive it fails with the follwoing error:

```
  Caused by: MetaException(message:Could not connect to meta store using any of the URIs provided. Most recent failure: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: GSS initiate failed

  [root@hdpm1 ~]# su - hive
  [hive@hdpm1 ~]$ hive
```

Comment: Are hadoop demons up and running?

Answer (score 0):

Before runing beeline you must get TGT using kinit
example for hive user using service keytab:

```
kinit -kt <path_to keystore> <principal_name>
kinit -kt /etc/security/keytabs/hive.service.keytab hive/<host>
```